# Automatically Restart Laravel Scheduler After Error

Tags: laravel

I've got a Laravel scheduler running, performing a named task every minute with "withoutOverlapping()" set. Now it errors out currently occasionally as I'm working on ironing out bugs as it runs. When it errors out however, it doesn't restart once I fix the error, not until I rename the task something else and wait till the next minute.

Even restarting Homestead doesn't kill and restart the scheduler. Is there some command I'm missing, or after a named task fails do you just have to rename it?

Comment: So what do you want to achieve? To try to run the same scheduler again until it passes or queue it again to run in X time?

Comment: I guess queue it again once the other one fails. So if it's set to run every minute without overlapping, if it fails and then I fix a line of code in it, I'd want it to attempt to run again once the next minute starts. I just assumed without overlapping would mean the task would end when failing, not hang permanently when failing until renamed?

Comment: try enveloping the code in `handler` under try-catch and in catch just set it to run the same thing again